# Lambda fails with "Cannot find module..."

Tags: node.js, webpack, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless

I'm packing my lambdas with Webpack. And I'm deploying them with CDK.

However, when testing them through ApiGateway, I get this:

> Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function
>   error: Error: Cannot find module 'apollo-server-lambda'.

Here's my Webpack config:

```
{
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    graphql: './src/lambdas/graphql.ts',
    cognito: './src/lambdas/cognito.ts',
    'smoke-detector': './src/lambdas/smoke-detector.ts',
  },
  output: {
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: '[name]/[name].js'
  },
  target: 'node',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      loader({
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'ts-loader',
          options: {
            getCustomTransformers: () => ({
              before: [graphqlTag.getTransformer()]
            })
          }
        }
      }),
      loader({
        test: /\.graphqls$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'graphql-tag/loader',
        }
      })
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
  ]
}
```

Executing the output file like `node graphql.js` doesn't fail. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: When I get this its normally due to a packing issue of some sort. Try and execute them through the lambda console and see if that gives the same error. If it does, download the zip file and check what's actually inside it.

Comment: @matthelliwell yeah, it's the same error. What do you think I should look for inside the lambda module?

Comment: @matthelliwell [here's the minimum content](https://gist.github.com/Birowsky/09cad646276e855b20c0b5d30e22ca99). Can you spot something?

Comment: I can't spot anything obvious. The things I check for when I get this are:
1. Path to the lambda in the console. It should be something like dist/src/smoketest.lambda. Make sure there isn't a leading slash on the path, the directory and file names are the correct case and the function name is correct.
2. The lambda module is in the correct place. I've had them appear in for example dist/smoketest instead of dist/srcs/smoketest.
3. The zip includes the smoketest.js file and you've not ended up with smoketest.ts by mistake.

Comment: Also download and unpack the zip file to a blank directory and try and run it from there using the same path as appears in the console, eg node -e "require('./dist/src/smoketest').lambda()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing

```
externals: [nodeExternals()]
```

fixed the problem.

It caused dependencies to be excluded from the bundle.